# What is a single-flash transistor-and-capacitor circuit actually called?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, flash, light

The internet is awash with diagrams where two lights alternately flash with the aid of transistors and capacitors. However, I remember at school being shown an introductory circuit in which one light lit up for a while and then went out as the second one switched on, to remain on permanently.

Despite searching for terms such as 'single flash circuit' or 'most basic transistor circuits', I have not been able to find the circuit diagram for it.

Can anyone tell me what this circuit is called? I remember it being an incredibly basic one, but the details I have long since forgotten.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator

Comment: google `one-shot`

Comment: i seem to remember an Silicon Control Rectifier (SCR) being used for something like that when I took an intro to electronics in high school...

Comment: monostable (multivibrator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are more than a few ways in which to create such a circuit; in general these are called "monostable multivibrators."  These can also be called a "one-shot" or "monoflop."

A "multivibrator" is an analog circuit which changes output state (emulating digital behavior) based on an input change. That input may be external to the circuit, preset to a defined state, or be the output of another multivibrator, creating several different possible behaviors.

The original inventors called these "multivibrators" because the output, due to using analog circuitry, was impure (imprecise) and thus, rich in harmonics (noise), especially at higher frequencies.

There are several variants of multivibrator, such as "astable" and "bistable".  The differences are:

- Astable: no inputs, unstable in either state; oscillates back-and-forth.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhKk31.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Monostable: one input, stable in one state only. Applying input causes output change, but output always reverts to original state after a delay. These are handy to "clean-up" a noisy switch for example.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAAZD1.png)</sup>

- Bistable: two inputs, stable in both output states. Applying an input change causes the output to change, and it will stay that way until the other input change happens. Commonly called "set" and "reset", which is a primitive form of latch or flip-flop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjL8nk.png)</sup>

There should be a "simulate" button under each of these... give them a try!

Comment: That's the name! It's all coming back to me now. It was the Vic-20 era when I think I last heard that term but that is exactly what my electronics teacher called it. Thanks.